# Problema con plugin Maven Swagger generator

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi

Estoy intentando generar mi Api con swagger generator pero me salta este error al incluir el plugin en maven.

Plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>
                            ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>io.tej.SwaggerCodgen.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>io.tej.SwaggerCodgen.model</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            ApiUtil.java
                        </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/main/java/</sourceFolder>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Aqui esta el error que me sale en consola al intentar generar el codigo con maven, no entiendo a que se refiere con el archivo de proceso de java.

```
    [INFO] Environment variable JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the Java code may not be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"' (Linux/Mac)
[INFO] NOTE: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).
[INFO] Invoker Package Name, originally not set, is now derived from api package name: io.tej.SwaggerCodgen
[INFO] Processing operation findEmployee
```

Comment: No encuentra algún archivo definido en la variable ``JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE`` . Podrías echarle un vistazo a  este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958611/how-to-generate-some-models-for-java-with-openapi-generator

Comment: lo que veo es que esto es para linux ? , yo estoy usando windows